# Как переместить фокус ввода с одного EditText на другой?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Есть три `EditText`

```
EditText etDay = (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.etDay);
EditText etMonth = (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.etMonth);
EditText etYear = (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.etYear);
```

Каждый из них имеет ограничение на длину ввода

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:hint="01"
        android:maxEms="2"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        >
    </EditText>
```

Как автоматически перевести фокус ввода (например с `etDay` на `etMonth`) если `etDay` заполнен?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может так?

```
etDay.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
         if (s.length() == 2) { 
             etMonth.requestFocus(); 
         }
    }
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
   }
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
           int count, int after) {
   }
});
```

Comment: Да, это решило проблему, благодарю!